# How to make sure the font stays the same when using ggsave

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

I'm trying to add multiple plots from ggplot into my Latex report. Most plots have different dimensions, as some need to be rectangle shaped, where as some need to be square shaped. To shape the plots, I've been changing the height and width parameters in ggsave. However, this also changes the font sizes. How do I have consistent font sizes for all my plots, and also be able to change the width and height of each plot separately?

I've already specified the font size in the plot using theme(text = element_text(size=5)), but it doesn't seem to actually stay consistent between the plots.

Comment: Related: https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2020/08/taking-control-of-plot-scaling/

Comment: I recommend using `theme(aspect.ratio = x)` instead of saving with different heights and widths. Makes for much more reproducible plots that allows for better and more true scaling.